# Centering my navigation menu links

Tags: css, navigation, centering, alignment

I just can't seem to figure this out. I've tried text-align: center; , display: inline-block and more but I just cant figure out how to center my navigation within the #menu-bottom-nav.

CSS

```
#menu-bottom-nav { width: 600px; height: 70px; margin: 0px auto;}
#menu-bottom-nav li { list-style-type: none; float: left; margin-right: 20px;}
```

Any help is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: how do you expect anything to happen if you float the li's left?!

Comment: Well if I don't they don't appear on the two lines like I want.

Comment: You cannot center items that do not have a fixed width.

Comment: yes you can center things without a fixed width, that's ridiculous.

Comment: when would they appear on two lines? here, i'll post an answer. without your HTML, there's no way we can determine what isn't happening...

Comment: If the tag is the same size as the text, as it is with an inline element, you cannot center the text BECAUSE THERE IS NO WHITESPACE.

Comment: yeah, that's if you're referring to inline elements. but we aren't talking about centering text in an inline element AT ALL. we're talking about centering LIs in a UL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
        #menu-bottom-nav {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            width: 600px;
            text-align: center;
            border: 1px solid #000;
        }

        #menu-bottom-nav li {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin-right: 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ff0000;
            display: inline-block;
            *display: inline;
            zoom: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu-bottom-nav">
        <li>Test</li>
        <li>Test2</li>
        <li>Test3</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks ianpgail. :) I'll remember this formatting and styling for my navigation menus.

Comment: no problem! you can use inline-block or inline, it's up to you!

Comment: I just seen it in IE 7 and it's not working there. Do you know why that might be?

Comment: I just added attributes to the CSS for "#menu-bottom-nav li" in my post. Try that out!

Comment: And that's all you need. Wow. Thanks again.

Comment: Haha no problem at all! I remember coming across this problem with IE7 before, so I just looked at some old code. Sorry I hadn't posted it before, I didn't realize you were targeting IE7 - I was just giving the quick, expected solution :)

Comment: I try to at least target for IE7. Hey, if you've run in to these types of things before, do you know of a great resource for IE hacks and prominent issues I can go to? I'm having issues with a couple more things on the site in IE 7.

Comment: I wish I could give you a reference, but when I come across problems, I honestly just Google it and find any solutions. I do try to target at least IE7, but that's usually after I finish something (not the right logic). The best I can tell you for now is that if you want to target it with CSS and you know specifically something you only want to happen in IE7, use the "*" like in my code. Otherwise, use Google to find things, such as http://www.webdevout.net/css-hacks

Comment: I Google a lot too. I'll just keep working at it it. I'll take a look at that link too. Thanks!